# Getting 2nd,3rd and 4th letter of nth element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the elements: '*rainbow*'*=*['*red*','*orange*','*yellow*','*green*','*blue*','*indigo*','*violet*']

And I want the second, third and fourth letters of one element of the list, in this case, '*orange*'. So in the end, I should have '*ran*'.

So far I have only got the 2nd,3rd,4th letters of all the elements with this code:

```
for i in rainbow:
       print(i[1:4]),
```

Answer (score 2):

You're a bit confused. If you simply want to retrieve the 2-4th letters of ***a single element, there is no need for a loop***. Identify the index of said element, and access it using list indexing. In your case, you want the element at the ***first*** index (list are zero indexed):

```
>>> rainbow = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']
>>> rainbow[1][1:4]
'ran'
```

If you want to ***find*** an element(s) in a list that match a certain criteria and print the 2-4th letters of  it (those), you can use a conditional statement in your `for`-loop:

```
>>> rainbow = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']
>>> for i in rainbow:
    if i == 'orange':
            print(i[1:4])


ran
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a general solution where you don't know the index, since it is a list you will need to find the corresponding index. So, here is a solution:

```
rainbow =['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']
word_to_search = 'orange'
index = rainbow.index(word_to_search)
print(rainbow[index][1:4])
```

**Output**

```
ran
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty good start. If you want it for a specific color you can search the list for the index of orange with `index = rainbow.index('orange')` to find orange, then call `orange = rainbow[index]` Then you can get the letts via `letters = orange[1:3]`. I added a truncated version in the program.

If I wanted to do it for the full list, I would do it with the following program

```
def main():
    rainbow = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']

    # If you want to print it for each color
    for color in rainbow:
        print(ith_letter(1, 4, color))

    # OR, If you want to print it for a specifi color

    orange = rainbow[rainbow.index('orange')]
    print(orange[1:4])


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def ith_letter(start, finish, string):

    # color may not contain 4 letters
    try:
        return string[start:finish]
    except:
        return ""

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Call main function
main()
```

Comment: Several points of critique. **(1)** It's never a good idea to have a bare `except:` clause. Always catch a specific exception(s). **(2)** You actually don't even need to use a `try/except` clause. Because of the way list slicing works in Python, it won't raise an error. e.g `'red'[1:1000]` returns `ed`. **(3)** In your code you have the correct slice `[1:4]`, but in your pretext you have an incorrect slice. _"Then you can get the letts via `letters = orange[1:3]`"_ should be _"Then you can get the letts via `letters = orange[1:4]`"_. Just some minor points.

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign the letters you want from the string to a variable, then print the variable

```
for i in rainbow:
    string = i[1:4] 
    print(string)
```

it works.  But be careful, you have to check if there are that much letters in the string.  For example red is 3 letters and it will give errors/unexpected result